# WOE and IV table in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a function that calculate WOE and IV as below:

```
def calc_iv(df, feature, target, pr=0):

    lst = []

    for i in range(df[feature].nunique()):
        val = list(df[feature].unique())[i]
        lst.append([feature, val, df[df[feature] == val].count()[feature], df[(df[feature] == val) & (df[target] == 1)].count()[feature]])

    data = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['Variable', 'Value', 'All', 'Bad'])
    data = data[data['Bad'] > 0]

    data['Share'] = data['All'] / data['All'].sum()
    data['Bad Rate'] = data['Bad'] / data['All']
    data['Distribution Good'] = (data['All'] - data['Bad']) / (data['All'].sum() - data['Bad'].sum())
    data['Distribution Bad'] = data['Bad'] / data['Bad'].sum()
    data['grp_score'] = round((data['Distribution Good']/(data['Distribution Good'] + data['Distribution Bad']))*10, 2)
    data['WoE'] = np.log(data['Distribution Good'] / data['Distribution Bad'])
    data['IV'] = (data['WoE'] * (data['Distribution Good'] - data['Distribution Bad'])).sum()
    data['Efficiency'] =  abs(data['Distribution Good'] - data['Distribution Bad'])/2  
    data = data.sort_values(by=['Variable', 'Value'], ascending=True)

    d = {data['Distribution Good'],data['Distribution Bad'],data['Share'],
         data['Bad Rate'],data['grp_score'],data['WoE'],data['IV'],data['Efficiency']}

    mydf=pd.DataFrame(data=d)

    if pr == 1:
        print(data)

    #return data['IV'].values[0]
    return mydf.values
```

the function checks a dataframe (dat) as below

```
myvar1 myvar2  myvar3  myvar4  target
 0       50     1000    7800     1
10       87     500     10000    0
35       0      3000    20000    0
```

I then call the function as below

```
calc_iv(dat, 'myvar1', 'target', pr=0)
```

I would want the function to return for myvar1

```
Distribution Good Distribution Bad Share Bad Rate grp_score WoE IV    Efficiency
 0.1                   0.9          1        0.9     20      0.2  0.6    0.8
 0.8                   0.2          2        0.2     10      0.1  0.2    0.1
 0.7                   0.3          3        0.3     70      0.7  0.8    0.5
```

but i get the below error

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, This has been quite for some time. But, for anyone hitting this issue. This, mainly, because of this code.

```
d = {data['Distribution Good'],data['Distribution Bad'],data['Share'],
         data['Bad Rate'],data['grp_score'],data['WoE'],data['IV'],data['Efficiency']}
```

The exception itself is thrown because the class `Series` extend `NDFrame`, which does not allow for it to be hashed (as seen in the source code [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/generic.py#L1835))

The most simple way would just to select the data like this

```
d = data[[
      'Distribution Good',
      'Distribution Bad',
      'Share',
      'Bad Rate',
      'grp_score',
      'WoE',
      'IV',
      'Efficiency'
  ]]
```

On a side note, if OP wants to get all result for those three rows. you probably want to remove this "filter" line.

`data = data[data['Bad'] > 0]`